# Trying to implement commutativity in Prolog

Tags: prolog, commutativity

I am trying to create a knowledge base. My problem has `terminal/1` and `connected/2` and I have defined the following rule:

```
connected(X,Y) :- connected(Y,X).
```

For reasons I now understand (I think), this went into an infinite recursion.

Then, I tried search SO and found this question: [Alternative to express "Commutativity" in Prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257947/alternative-to-express-commutativity-in-prolog)
. Based on the answers provided, I tried to change my above fact to the following:

```
connected(X, Y) :- is_connected(Y, X) /\ is_connected(X, Y).
is_connected(X, Y) :- terminal(X) /\ terminal(Y) /\ connected(X , Y).
```

However, this doesn't give me the results I was hoping for. If I define a rule `connected(t1,t7)`, I am hoping to get `yes` if I ask the question `connected(t7,t1)`.

Comment: You are using `/\` in SWI? This should be rather `,`.

Comment: You mean `,` rather than `forward-slash back-slash`?

Comment: Yes. `(',')/2` is conjunction in Prolog.

Comment: Out of curiosity- is it wrong to use forward-slash back-slash for conjuction? I'm finding the resources are not clear about this...

Comment: `/\` is only defined for arithmetic expressions meaning bitwise and. It is not defined as a goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure this out.

I changed this:

```
connected(X, Y) :- is_connected(Y, X) /\ is_connected(X, Y).
is_connected(X, Y) :- terminal(X) /\ terminal(Y) /\ connected(X , Y).
```

to:

```
is_connected(X, Y) :- connected(Y, X); connected(X, Y).
```

As it turns out, I also need to be asking the corrected question. Instead of asking `connected(X,Y)`, I will now be asking `is_connected(X,Y)`.